# Why big difference between categorical and continous variable inregression analysis?

Tags: regression, categorical-data, survival, continuous-data

I am currently doing a survival analysis where I want to adjust for several confounders. One of my variables, which I will name MyScore is a score from 1-5. When I enter MyScore as a continuous variable it loses its predictive value after a few steps, but when I enter it as a categorical it is not removed and is one of the independent predictors.
Does anyone can explain why this is happening, and how you decide how to enter your variable? Thanks!

Comment: If you enter the variable as categorical, then dummy variables are created in the model for the levels. Apart from statistical reasoning, it is important if the model with the variable entered as categorical makes sense. Maybe the effect only counts for the samples with high scores for example, which could make sense; otherwise it could just be a glitch or a case of over-fitting.

Comment: If you include MyScore as continuos, you are assuming a linear relationship between the variable and the response, and maybe you have other kind of relation: quadratic, for example. Or maybe only one of the 5 categories are related with the response